# How to update an attribute with a link in Rails4 w/ Strong Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am wanting to be able to click a link and update an attribute `is_public` in rails4 with strong parameters. Here is my current code:

```
<small><%= link_to "make private", property_url(@property,is_public: !@property.is_public), method: "patch" %></small>
```

The issue I have with this, is in the controller the strong parameters will receive a No Method for Nil Class for the `.permit` method because it doesn't create `params[property][:is_public]`. It just creates `params[:is_public]` and the ID of the property.

Is there a rails way of making it nest the parameters in the object or will I have to hard code (I don't even like hard coding my name) this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saying that you want the action behind your link to be able to update its data with:

```
@property.update(property_params)
```

Where the strong parameters are something like:

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:is_public)
end
```

Then I think you could define your link as:

```
<small><%= link_to "make private", property_url(@property, property: { is_public: !@property.is_public }), method: "patch" %></small>
```

And that would line up the parameters in the typical way.  Is that what you're after?